# How to store long and int value in a single variable

Tags: java

suppose a user input is " 123 " then this code is fail because long int is defined.

When 13964599874 is user input then this is code working fine.

user input "123" and "13964599874".

user input is dynamic.

Comment: What? I don't see the problem with defining the variable as a long.

Comment: There is no user input in this code sample. Also 123 would be perfectly storable in a long int.

Comment: You can use the long data type to store a value within the bounds of an int

Comment: If you take in user input as string, you can separately try to parse it as a int and long

Comment: Just cast it to a long before storing.  Should work just fine.

Comment: If you use wrapper classes like Long or Integer then you could only use Number as common super type, but why not using long primitive??? You will hardly want to assign null?!

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results. Include any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on [ask] and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the primitive type `long`.

```
long value;

value = Long.parseLong(imputString);
```

The above will work for any valid long value that is represented as a string.
This is any number between -2^63 and (2^63 - 1).
This range includes all possible int values.

Read the [Long JavaDoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).
The `parseLong` method will throw a `NumberFormatException` which is unchecked,
but you should still catch it.